# UIButton function with target nil doens´t get called?

Tags: ios, uibutton, target

i´ve made lots of my own "CustomUIButton" in a for-loop in my viewcontroller. 
In this "CustomUIButton"-class i´ve implemented an UIGestureRecognizer like this:

```
    (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {

    // custom things.

     UILongPressGestureRecognizer* longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
            longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
            [self addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
            [longPress release];
    }
}

    - (void) handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*) recognizer{

        if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
            NSLog(@"Long press Ended");
        }
        else {

            NSLog(@"Long press detected.");
             // Do something
        }
    }
```

If i init the target with "self", my "handleLongPress"-function in this class will be called. It´s cool. If i init the target with "nil", it should check the parent viewcontroller, right?

Any ideas why an additional function with the same name in my viewcontroller won´t be called? (For this test i´ve commented the "longpress"-function of the button-class out.)

Comment: What platform and framework are you using? From the "NS" prefix on "NSLog", and the syntax that looks like Objective-C, I would guess this is something for Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the docs for UIGestureRecognizer's [`initWithTarget:action:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer) method, for the `target` parameter it says:

> An object that is the recipient of
>   action messages sent by the receiver
>   when it recognizes a gesture. **nil is
>   not a valid value.**

Note the last sentence.

The docs also say this which should explain why it doesn't work:

> A gesture recognizer does not
>   participate in the view’s responder
>   chain.

You must specify a value for `target`.